# how to transform my c++ for exe to a code for dll

Tags: c++, dll

I have a c++ class that I've defined in a header file **testclass.hpp**  the code works fine in as an **.exe** now I want to use it for a **dll**  and I don't know how to do it I visted MSDN site and did what they tell there but in didn'T help , any idea how to do this. here a code example :

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <iostream>


class Test{
    private: 
     int variable1;
     int variable2;
    public:
     Test(float,int);
     ~Test();
     void doStuff();
     int getstuff();

};
#endif
```

and this is what I tried :

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H
#ifndef TESTCLASSDLL_EXPORTS
#define TESTCLASSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#endif
#define TESTCLASSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#include <iostream>


class Test{
    private: 
    static __declspec(dllexport) int variable1;
    static __declspec(dllexport) int variable2;
    public:
    TESTCLASSDLL_API Test(float,int);
    TESTCLASSDLL_API ~Test();
    TESTCLASSDLL_API void doStuff();
    TESTCLASSDLL_API int getstuff();

};
#endif
```

Comment: And you didn't put declare that as `class TESTCLASSDLL_API Test` because...?

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't get what you mean

Comment: I mean it would appear you want to export the class, including its members (both function and variables). You can do that by simply using your macro from above and wedging it between `class` and your class name. All the declspec and macro use inside your class is not needed.

Comment: ok? can you please write a code example so I can understand it thanks in advance!

Comment: nope, but I can send you [somewhere that has already done so](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+exporting+a+class+from+a+dll).